# How to fix a broken Angular CLI installation in Windows?

Tags: angular, windows-10, angular-cli

I manually deleted some @angular folders because 'ng v' kept showing me older versions of Angular even though I cleared the npm cache and reinstalled Angular CLI several times and reopened the console window.

I did a:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

I get now the error below when I run 'ng v' because of the missing @angular subfolder. I thought installing the CLI would install that folder. Is there a way to get Angular back into a working order without this error?

[image]

Comment: Try
`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
`rm -rf node_modules`
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
`ng new my-project`

Comment: rm is a Linux and I am on Windows and I don't want to delete the whole folder. But that gave me an idea. I renamed node_modules to something else and installed the CLI. It created a new node_modules with an @angular subfolder. So I copied it to the renamed folder, deleted node_modules and renamed the other folder back to node_modules. Success.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed node_modules to something else and installed the CLI. It created a new node_modules with an @angular subfolder. So I copied it to the renamed folder, deleted node_modules and renamed the other folder back to node_modules.